# Sort pandas dataframe based on a particular ordering

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, merge

given data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    a = ['cup', 'plate', 'apple', 'seal'],
    b = ['s','sf', 'wer', 'sdfg']
))
```

Which is:

```
       a     b
0    cup     s
1  plate    sf
2  apple   wer
3   seal  sdfg
```

How to order it as

```
apple
seal
cup
plate
```

An approach that works but seems overkill:

```py
ordering = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    a = [ "apple", "seal", "cup", "plate" ],
    c = [0,1,2,3]
))
pd.merge(df, ordering, left_on="a", right_on="a", how="left").sort_values(["c"]).drop(
    ["c"], axis=1
)
```

Comment: Set 'a' as the index of the df and pass a list with the desired order.

Comment: @JuanJavierSantosOchoa thanks - is this the approach that Siggy has taken in this thread? With `df.set_index('a').loc[order].reset_index()`?

Comment: Yes! That is the approach

Comment: @JuanJavierSantosOchoa cheers - would you consider this more standard than using a categorical like the other answer? i'm just thinking about others finding it, they both work... perhaps i should speed test them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC `Categorical`

```
df=df.iloc[pd.Categorical(df.a, ['apple','seal','cup','plate']).argsort()]
df
Out[235]: 
       a     b
2  apple   wer
3   seal  sdfg
0    cup     s
1  plate    sf
```

Comment: thank you, is there any approach between this and `df.set_index('a').loc[order].reset_index()` which might be considered more standard?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use `a` as an index and then use the [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=lookup#different-choices-for-indexing) indexing trick:

```
order = ["apple", "seal", "cup", "plate"]
df.set_index('a').loc[order].reset_index()
```

That gives

```
       a     b
0  apple   wer
1   seal  sdfg
2    cup     s
3  plate    sf
```

Regarding your followup question, if you add an apple to the end of the original dataframe you will get multiple apples returned:

```
           b
a
apple    wer
apple  sasda
seal    sdfg
cup        s
plate     sf
```

The index does not have to be unique. If you have [duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) in your index, all of them will be returned by `.loc`.

Comment: "* Do you intend to use the sort_values method of the data frame*", no as this won't result in the correct (custom) ordering

Comment: I removed the first part of the answer where i didn't understand the intended ordering.